# MDX query using parameters is not filtering right

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I built a dataset and choose to use filters as parameter. I used the hierarchy project path = "DefaultCollection", work item.work item type = "Task", work item linked.work item type = "Demand", work item.ID  = "All" and work item linked.Id = "All". So long everything is just fine.

The SSRS built a hidden dataset to populate the work item.Id filter dropdown. This dropdown is populated with lot of unfiltered result. I was expecting only the task id within the defaultCollection, work item type "Task' and work item linked.work item type "Demand".

I check the this dataset mdx query and it seems fine, but now I am stuck.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
    [Work Item].[System_Id].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
    [Work Item].[System_Id].CurrentMember.UniqueName 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
    [Work Item].[System_Id].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[ParameterCaption]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterValue]
   ,[Measures].[ParameterLevel]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Work Item].[System_Id].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    StrToSet
    (@WorkItemLinkedSystemId
     ,CONSTRAINED
    ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      StrToSet
      (@WorkItemLinkedSystemWorkItemType
       ,CONSTRAINED
      ) ON COLUMNS
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        StrToSet
        (@WorkItemSystemWorkItemType
         ,CONSTRAINED
        ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          StrToSet
          (@TeamProjectProjectPath
           ,CONSTRAINED
          ) ON COLUMNS
        FROM [Work Item]
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I appreciated any help. Thanks

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Why the dropdown is populated with lot of unfiltered result. I was expecting only the task id within the defaultCollection, work item type "Task' and work item linked.work item type "Demand". It comes lot of entries that do not obey that criteria.